# Is infinite/countable subsets of infinite/countable topological spaces are dense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space where $X$ is either countable or infinite. If the topology is the co-finite topology, we can say that for any countable/infinite subset $H$ of  countable/infinite $X$ is dense in $X$. If we do not know the topology on $X$, what can we say about density of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no reason to expect an infinite set to be dense.  Consider for instance $H= \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the usual Euclidean topology.  Then $H$ is countably infinite but certainly not dense.  One can construct many more examples like this.

Comment: .Thank you, I should have thought more before  asking.